# PHP doesn't pick the long URL parameter that I'm passing to the URL, any way around it?

Tags: php, google-visualization

I'm passing a very long URL parameter in the URL below .. but  it only returns  `"["` with the get method .. Below is the URL

What can I do to fix this .. What I actually did in php is this, the variable $data_for_chart contains the whole parameter that you see above .. It's imperative that I have the parameters with brackets and commas that separate it because I will use it to generate the google charts in productsum2.php

```
 echo "<p><a class='iframe' href='productsums2.php?id=".$data_for_chart."'>Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>"; 

<a class='iframe' href='productsums2.php?id=['Tutorial', 0],
['Website How To', 0],
['Photos', 0],
['Tutorial', 0],
['Website How To', 0],
['Photos', 0],
['Core Values', 0],
['Corporate Tour', 0],
['Customer Testimonials', 0],
['Introduction', 0],
['Electrical Assemblies', 0],
['Electrical Connectors', 0],
['Air Assemblies', 0],
['Air Connectors', 0],
['Wire & Cable', 0],
['Battery Terminals & Accessories', 0],
['Wire Terminals', 0],
['Heat Shrink Tubing', 0],
['Cable/Wire Support & Accessories', 0],
['Trailer Harness System', 0],
['Dome Lamps & Controllers', 0],
['Tools', 0],
['Traffic Builders', 0],
['Full Catalog', 0],
['CSA QWIK-FIX Roadside Repair Kit', 0],
['Anodized Swinger Gladhand', 0],
['STA-LOCK Cast Iron Swinger Gladhand', 0],
['Battery Status Indicator', 0],
['QBOX', 0],
['CHARGE-BOX', 0],
['Tracker Bar Spring Kit', 0],
['STA-DRY Document Holder', 0],
['24 Volt Fleet Essential', 0],
['L-ALC - ABS Lectracoil 02-03-11', 0],
['L-BSI - Battery Status Indicator  NEW 2-06-12', 0],
['L-EALA - Elec and Air Line Assy 3n1.pdf', 0],
['L-EHD - STA-DRY Harness Brochure 2-06-12', 0],
['L-LWWT - LECTRACOIL with WEATHER-TITE 02-08-12', 1],
['L-PA - Polar Air', 0],
['L-PLXB - PERMALITE XB', 0],
['L-QCS2 - QCS2', 1],
['L-QE - QWIK-E', 0],
['L-S7WC - STA-DRY 7-Way Connetors 2-07-12', 0],
['L-SLCISG - Cast Iron Swinger Gladhands', 0],
['L-SLG - STA-LOCK Gladhand', 0],
['L-SLIM -  Slim-7', 1],
['L-SQCMS - STA-DRY QCMS 02-08-12', 1],
['L-ST - STA-DRY Tracker 02-08-12', 4],
['L-SWG - Swinger Gladhand', 1],
['L-VC1 - Vcheck 1  02-09-12', 0],
['L-VC2 - Vcheck2 02-09-12', 2],
['Permalogic Family inside and outside', 4],
['STA-DRY PRO System - Brochure', 3],
['L-WTC-WEATHER-TITE', 4],
['POLAR AIR&#174;', 0],
['LECTRACOIL&#153; WITH QCP&#153; (Quick-Connect Plug)', 0],
['PERMALITE&#153; XB', 0],
['PERMALOGIC&#153; FAMILY', 0],
['STA-DRY&#174; 7-Way Connectors', 0],
['STA-DRY&#174; 7-Way Connectors ', 0],
['QWIK-E&#174; Gladhand ', 0],
['STA-DRY&#174; SLIM7&#153; ', 0],
['STA-DRY&#174;  QCS2&#153;', 1]'>Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need can try to URL encode that before trying to pass it.

**PHP Code**

```
$Param = <<<LONG
['Tutorial', 0],
['Website How To', 0],
['Photos', 0],
['Tutorial', 0],
['Website How To', 0],
['Photos', 0],
['Core Values', 0],
['Corporate Tour', 0],
['Customer Testimonials', 0],
['Introduction', 0],
['Electrical Assemblies', 0],
['Electrical Connectors', 0],
['Air Assemblies', 0],
['Air Connectors', 0],
['Wire & Cable', 0],
['Battery Terminals & Accessories', 0],
['Wire Terminals', 0],
['Heat Shrink Tubing', 0],
['Cable/Wire Support & Accessories', 0],
['Trailer Harness System', 0],
['Dome Lamps & Controllers', 0],
['Tools', 0],
['Traffic Builders', 0],
['Full Catalog', 0],
['CSA QWIK-FIX Roadside Repair Kit', 0],
['Anodized Swinger Gladhand', 0],
['STA-LOCK Cast Iron Swinger Gladhand', 0],
['Battery Status Indicator', 0],
['QBOX', 0],
['CHARGE-BOX', 0],
['Tracker Bar Spring Kit', 0],
['STA-DRY Document Holder', 0],
['24 Volt Fleet Essential', 0],
['L-ALC - ABS Lectracoil 02-03-11', 0],
['L-BSI - Battery Status Indicator  NEW 2-06-12', 0],
['L-EALA - Elec and Air Line Assy 3n1.pdf', 0],
['L-EHD - STA-DRY Harness Brochure 2-06-12', 0],
['L-LWWT - LECTRACOIL with WEATHER-TITE 02-08-12', 1],
['L-PA - Polar Air', 0],
['L-PLXB - PERMALITE XB', 0],
['L-QCS2 - QCS2', 1],
['L-QE - QWIK-E', 0],
['L-S7WC - STA-DRY 7-Way Connetors 2-07-12', 0],
['L-SLCISG - Cast Iron Swinger Gladhands', 0],
['L-SLG - STA-LOCK Gladhand', 0],
['L-SLIM -  Slim-7', 1],
['L-SQCMS - STA-DRY QCMS 02-08-12', 1],
['L-ST - STA-DRY Tracker 02-08-12', 4],
['L-SWG - Swinger Gladhand', 1],
['L-VC1 - Vcheck 1  02-09-12', 0],
['L-VC2 - Vcheck2 02-09-12', 2],
['Permalogic Family inside and outside', 4],
['STA-DRY PRO System - Brochure', 3],
['L-WTC-WEATHER-TITE', 4],
['POLAR AIR&#174;', 0],
['LECTRACOIL&#153; WITH QCP&#153; (Quick-Connect Plug)', 0],
['PERMALITE&#153; XB', 0],
['PERMALOGIC&#153; FAMILY', 0],
['STA-DRY&#174; 7-Way Connectors', 0],
['STA-DRY&#174; 7-Way Connectors ', 0],
['QWIK-E&#174; Gladhand ', 0],
['STA-DRY&#174; SLIM7&#153; ', 0],
['STA-DRY&#174;  QCS2&#153;', 1]
LONG;

echo rawurlencode($Param);
```

**Outputs**

```
%5B%27Tutorial%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Website%20How%20To%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Photos%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Tutorial%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Website%20How%20To%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Photos%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Core%20Values%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Corporate%20Tour%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Customer%20Testimonials%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Introduction%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Electrical%20Assemblies%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Electrical%20Connectors%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Air%20Assemblies%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Air%20Connectors%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Wire%20%26%20Cable%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Battery%20Terminals%20%26%20Accessories%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Wire%20Terminals%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Heat%20Shrink%20Tubing%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Cable%2FWire%20Support%20%26%20Accessories%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Trailer%20Harness%20System%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Dome%20Lamps%20%26%20Controllers%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Tools%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Traffic%20Builders%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Full%20Catalog%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27CSA%20QWIK-FIX%20Roadside%20Repair%20Kit%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Anodized%20Swinger%20Gladhand%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27STA-LOCK%20Cast%20Iron%20Swinger%20Gladhand%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Battery%20Status%20Indicator%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27QBOX%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27CHARGE-BOX%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Tracker%20Bar%20Spring%20Kit%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27STA-DRY%20Document%20Holder%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%2724%20Volt%20Fleet%20Essential%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-ALC%20-%20ABS%20Lectracoil%2002-03-11%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-BSI%20-%20Battery%20Status%20Indicator%20%20NEW%202-06-12%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-EALA%20-%20Elec%20and%20Air%20Line%20Assy%203n1.pdf%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-EHD%20-%20STA-DRY%20Harness%20Brochure%202-06-12%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-LWWT%20-%20LECTRACOIL%20with%20WEATHER-TITE%2002-08-12%27%2C%201%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-PA%20-%20Polar%20Air%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-PLXB%20-%20PERMALITE%20XB%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-QCS2%20-%20QCS2%27%2C%201%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-QE%20-%20QWIK-E%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-S7WC%20-%20STA-DRY%207-Way%20Connetors%202-07-12%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-SLCISG%20-%20Cast%20Iron%20Swinger%20Gladhands%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-SLG%20-%20STA-LOCK%20Gladhand%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-SLIM%20-%20%20Slim-7%27%2C%201%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-SQCMS%20-%20STA-DRY%20QCMS%2002-08-12%27%2C%201%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-ST%20-%20STA-DRY%20Tracker%2002-08-12%27%2C%204%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-SWG%20-%20Swinger%20Gladhand%27%2C%201%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-VC1%20-%20Vcheck%201%20%2002-09-12%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-VC2%20-%20Vcheck2%2002-09-12%27%2C%202%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27Permalogic%20Family%20inside%20and%20outside%27%2C%204%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27STA-DRY%20PRO%20System%20-%20Brochure%27%2C%203%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27L-WTC-WEATHER-TITE%27%2C%204%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27POLAR%20AIR%26%23174%3B%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27LECTRACOIL%26%23153%3B%20WITH%20QCP%26%23153%3B%20%28Quick-Connect%20Plug%29%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27PERMALITE%26%23153%3B%20XB%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27PERMALOGIC%26%23153%3B%20FAMILY%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27STA-DRY%26%23174%3B%207-Way%20Connectors%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27STA-DRY%26%23174%3B%207-Way%20Connectors%20%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27QWIK-E%26%23174%3B%20Gladhand%20%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27STA-DRY%26%23174%3B%20SLIM7%26%23153%3B%20%27%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%5B%27STA-DRY%26%23174%3B%20%20QCS2%26%23153%3B%27%2C%201%5D
```

**Caveat**

Even if you do url encode it, the maximum limit for a URL is 1024kb or 2048kb based on the browser. It will still be cut off. You need to POST this or find another way to transmit it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes on your href value, then again inside of it.  You'll have to escape the single quotes inside the href value or use double ouble quotes on your href value.

edit: so this is all the href is seeing right now using single quotes on the outside and inside of the value:

```
href='productsums2.php?id=['
```

The rest it doesn't care about because it found it's ending single quote.

Comment: since you are using echo with double quotes, you could just put an escaped double quote around your href value like this: echo "<a href=\"these'single'quotes'will'still'work\">link text</a>";